# Form php/html send radio buttons into html email also not filled in items (radio buttons)

Tags: php, html, session, webforms

I want to fill in this form / but when filled in i want it to send me all the radio buttons (images) and also the not filled in buttons.

for example i get options
radio
   - no
   - yes
   - maybe

clicked on maybe. When the mail has been send i get it as HTML. looks good.
but now i want even the image (radiobutton) to be send with the data and also the not filled in items:
This is how i want to get it in my email..
   -   no
   -   yes
   |-| maybe

This is part of the code:

```
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Algemene indruk werkkleding</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nr8']) . "</td></tr>\r\n";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Logboek afgetekend</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nr9']) . "</td></tr>\r\n";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Materialen gekeurd</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['nr10']) . "</td></tr>\r\n";
```

And how it looks on the HTML part:

```
    <div class="rowElem">
        <label for="nr6">Algemene indruk werkkast</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr6" value="Goed">
            <label>Goed</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr6" value="Matig">
            <label>Voldoende</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr6" value="Niet Goed">
            <label>Onvoldoende</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr6" value="NVT">
            <label>NVT</label>
    </div>

            <div class="rowElem">
        <label for="nr7">Algemene indruk werkwagen</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr7" value="Goed">
            <label>Goed</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr7" value="Matig">
            <label>Voldoende</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr7" value="Niet Goed">
            <label>Onvoldoende</label>
            <input type="radio" name="nr7" value="NVT">
            <label>NVT</label>
    </div><br>
```

I really hope someone can help me if you need a link where the code is:

www.lubke.nl/form/index.php
This is where it is standing:
Im sorry if I sound like a rooky but this is one of my first forms made for myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could just fill in the blanks server side when you receive the POST.  If you know the entirety of the values, you could simply combine that with what you receive.

```
$baseValues = ['nr1' => '', 'nr2' => '', 'nr3' => '', ...];

$baseValues = array_merge($baseValues, $_POST);

//build your email using the $baseValues, rather than $_POST...
```

Another common workaround would be to use hidden inputs to maintain actual values and use check-boxes/radio buttons to just manipulate the value of the corresponding hidden inputs.  But that would require additional work on the client side with JS.